# Forcing `imshow` to properly color pixels based on `Colormap` colors when not all values are present in image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on visualizing the output of semantic segmentation neural network. For this I have a set of labels(classes) and corresponding colors for pixels. I am displaying the data using `matplotlib` `imshow`. Each pixel is represented by a value `[0, num_classes]` corresponding to these labels and colors. Some of the data I am displaying does not contain all of the labels from the entire set. I have found that this results incorrect labelling based on how I am implementing my calls to `imshow`.

This SSCCEE outlines the issue:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap


label_dict = {
    0: 'unlabelled',
    1: 'label1',
    2: 'label2',
    3: 'label3',
    4: 'label4',
    5: 'label5'
}

color_dict = {
    0: 'black',
    1: 'rebeccapurple',
    2: 'darkgrey',
    3: 'wheat',
    4: 'lime',
    5: 'red'
}

num_labels = len(color_dict)
correct_color_data = np.arange(0, num_labels) * np.ones((num_labels, num_labels))
incorrect_color_data = np.array([2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]) * np.ones((num_labels, num_labels))

fig = plt.figure()

ax_0 = plt.subplot(121)
cm = ListedColormap(color_dict.values())
cax = ax_0.imshow(correct_color_data, cmap=cm, interpolation='none')
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=list(label_dict.keys()))
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(label_dict.values())

ax_1 = plt.subplot(122)
cm = ListedColormap(color_dict.values())
cax = ax_1.imshow(incorrect_color_data, cmap=cm, interpolation='none')
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=list(label_dict.keys()))
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(label_dict.values())

plt.show()
```

The plot generated by this code:

[image]

You'll notice on the right the data that in image only contains the values `2, 3, 4` but colors these pixels as if they were `0, 3, 5`. It also only shows the label ticks for `2, 3, 4` in these locations and none of the other label ticks.

**How can I force `imshow` to properly label pixels it displays based on their value in relation to a custom `Colormap`?** Further, how can I force `Colorbar` to add tick labels for all labels even if they do not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `imshow()` with `vmin=0, vmax=5` to tell matplotlib the range of the values. By default, `vmin` and `vmax` are set to `min(data)` and `max(data)`. This will also set the ticks at the same positions in both plots.

To have the ticks in the center of the cells, you can use `colorbar(..., ticks=np.linspace(0, 5, 11)[1::2])`. Note that the first parameter to `colorbar()` is the graphical element that has been colored. Optionally, `shrink=` can be set to scale down the colorbar.  The colorbar gets a default height, but the `imshow()` plot defaults to having a square aspect ratio, which can change either the height or the width depending on the available space.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

label_dict = {0: 'unlabelled',
              1: 'label1',
              2: 'label2',
              3: 'label3',
              4: 'label4',
              5: 'label5'}
color_dict = {0: 'black',
              1: 'rebeccapurple',
              2: 'darkgrey',
              3: 'wheat',
              4: 'lime',
              5: 'red'}
num_labels = len(color_dict)
correct_color_data = np.arange(0, num_labels) * np.ones((num_labels, num_labels))
incorrect_color_data = np.array([2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]) * np.ones((num_labels, num_labels))
imin = min(label_dict)
imax = max(label_dict)

fig, (ax_0, ax_1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.4})

cm = ListedColormap(color_dict.values())
img0 = ax_0.imshow(correct_color_data, cmap=cm, interpolation='none', vmin=imin, vmax=imax)
cbar = fig.colorbar(img0, ticks=np.linspace(imin, imax, 2 * num_labels + 1)[1::2], shrink=0.45, ax=ax_0)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(label_dict.values())

cm = ListedColormap(color_dict.values())
img1 = ax_1.imshow(incorrect_color_data, cmap=cm, interpolation='none', vmin=imin, vmax=imax)
cbar = fig.colorbar(img1, ticks=np.linspace(imin, imax, 2 * num_labels + 1)[1::2], shrink=0.45, ax=ax_1)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(label_dict.values())

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: You can suppress the tick markers of the colorbar with `cbar.ax.tick_params(length=0)`.